# How to restore text broken due to wrong encoding in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, encoding, codepages

I use Delphi 2009. I receive a text as String that looks like 'Р’РёР·РіСѓРЅРѕРІ (СЂР°РЅРЅРёР№) {VHS}'. Using online decoders, I was able to determine that it's actually Win-1251 codepage.

What should I do to restore it back to normal, in other words to make it readable again?

Comment: How are you receiving the text to begin with? What is the text *supposed* to look like? Please provide more detail, preferrably a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s: string;
    rbs: RawByteString;
begin
    rbs := Utf8ToAnsi('Р’РёР·РіСѓРЅРѕРІ (СЂР°РЅРЅРёР№) {VHS}');
    SetCodePage(rbs, 1251, false);
    s := string(rbs); // s = 'Визгунов (ранний) {VHS}'
end;
```